# AngularJS change Location and set Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to change page and set a new controller.
Actually I'm using this code to routing:

```
bbApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/meetings', {
                templateUrl: CONTEXT_PATH+'/get/meeting/list.html',
                controller: 'MeetingListController'
            }).
            when('/meetings/:meetingId', {
                templateUrl: CONTEXT_PATH+'/get/meeting/listItems.html',
                controller: 'FolderListController',
                params: {meetingList: meetingsArray}
            }).
            when('/items/:meetingId/:itemId/:itemsTitle/:lan/', {
                templateUrl: CONTEXT_PATH+'/get/meeting/view.html',
                controller: 'DocumentViewController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/meetings'
            });
}]);
```

Now I have to change page from controller and set new Controller tomanage new page.

I'm using this:

```
$location.path(CONTEXT_PATH+'/get/meeting/listItems.html');
```

How can set controller?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"/meetings/"+meetingId` where the `meetingId` is a variable in your controller. You are using routing therefore I think it should work this way

Comment: I can't use .config because I have to change page after some operations into controller, if I use .config as soon as I click page changes. I don't have to link change page with a controller variable,I need to match the right controller after changing page.

Comment: If you have to do some stuff before page changes, simply use ng-click function, and at the end of it invoke $state.go statement to change the state.